# Literal constant suffixes when initializing variables

Tags: c++

Is it a good practice to always use suffixes when initializing variables? What about these cases?

```
float foo = 0.0F;
unsigned int bar = 0U;
```

Or would you only use literal suffixes when there might be a conversion problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [cpp FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#numeric-literal-suffixes)

> You should use these suffixes when you need to force the compiler to treat the numeric literal as if it were the specified type

There's also a good example:

If `x` is of type float, the expression `x + 5.7` is of type `double`: it first promotes the value of `x` to a `double`, then performs the arithmetic using double-precision instructions. If that is what you want, fine; but if you really wanted it to do the arithmetic using single-precision instructions, you can change that code to `x + 5.7f`.

There are also readability reasons

> If you end up using unsigned variables, it is generally a good idea to force your numeric literals to also be unsigned. That makes it easier to see that the compiler will generate “unsigned arithmetic” instructions.

Comment: Does this mean "only use literal suffix when there might be a conversion problem" or "good praxis to always use suffixes"?

Comment: It means: `it is a good discipline for programmers to force all numeric operands to be of the right type, as opposed to relying on the C++ rules for promoting/demoting numeric expressions`. If the 'right' type is the one you would get anyway without literals, it doesn't quite matter.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Is there a cost associated with "float foo = 0.0;" ? Or is this converted to a float at compile time?

Comment: Not with that one, but there would be at runtime in case of the following: `float x = 1.0f; auto dd = x + 5.7;` since there would be a float2double conversion involved (sign extension in this specific case)